# Why SingleTon instance is in memory even after exiting the application

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, singleton, mef

I am Building a `MyServiceLibrary` instance by passing it `IServiceProvider` object and then get the singleton instance by `GetInstance()`

```
 _serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)GetInterface("IServiceProvider");  
    MyServicesLibrary.BuildInstance(_serviceProvider);
   var _myserviceLib= MyServicesLibrary.GetInstance();
```

BuildInstance is :

```
 public static void BuildInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (serviceProvider == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceProvider");
        }

        if (_singletonInstance == null)
        {
            _singletonInstance = new MyServicesLibrary(serviceProvider);
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
    }
```

and `GetInstance` just returns the built object.

```
public static MyServicesLibrary GetInstance()
        {
            if (_singletonInstance == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("BuildInstance method should be called first");
            }
            return _singletonInstance;
        }
```

But the problem is , when I run the application for the first time  and set a break point on `BuildInstance` , `_singletonInstance` is null and then it creates the instance.

Then I close the application and re-run it. Surprisingly ,`_singletonInstance`  is not null at this time . I am not able to understand how come  _singletonInstance   is not getting deleted from memory when I close the application.

Any pointers please?

Comment: Generally, you won't be able to read memory from another process. Not unless you specifically call into kernel or use functions like [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Are you sure the state is not saved in a file (for example config file) or you have some conditional check in the code that changes its condition after application started - e.g. application creates a file, you check if this file exists, during first run there is no file present, after the first run the file is there?

Comment: No , App is not saving it's state on any file.

Comment: Your tags say 'wpf', is that how your code above is running? Or is this code hosted in a web server? If the former I do not see how it could happen but if the latter, any singletons would not go out of scope until the web server instance / app pool was restarted.

Comment: Can you post a small full sample to reproduce a problem?